# Use MATLAB's 'keyPressFcn' in a simple program

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am trying to use the 'KeyPressFcn' in a normal MATLAB script, but I am having problems. I can use it nicely WITHIN a function, ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613252/how-to-use-keypressfcn-in-matlab-with-a-function-already-create)), but I would like to use it in a normal script like so.

My simple script is:

```
%Entry Point
clear all

N = 100;
x = randn(1,N);

figHandle = figure(1);
clf(figHandle);
set(figHandle, 'KeyPressFcn', myFunction(~, eventDat,x,N))
```

Here is the function 'myFunction' that sits in the same directory:

```
function myFunction(~, eventDat,x,N)

    mean = sum(x)/N;
    disp(mean);
    key = eventDat.Key;
    disp(key);

end
```

Now, if I run this, it does not work, because, (I suspect), something is wrong with the way I am calling myFunction, but I cannot figure out what the problem is exactly, since I am a noob at using KeyPressFcn. Help would be appreciated for this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it through anonymous functions:

In script file, for example called `test.m`:

```
%Entry Point
clear all

N = 100;
x = randn(1,N);

figHandle = figure(1);
clf(figHandle);
set(figHandle, 'KeyPressFcn', ...
    @(fig_obj , eventDat) myFunction(fig_obj, eventDat, x, N));
```

In a file called `myFunction.m` in the same folder as test.m

```
function myFunction(~, eventDat, x, N)

    mean = sum(x)/N;
    disp(mean);
    key = eventDat.Key;
    disp(key);
```

---

How to return value from myFunction? 
There are [few ways](http://goo.gl/YzEBW8) of doing this. It depends on what u want to do. But quickly you could use mutable variables for this, such as, `containers.Map`. This is one example of ding this. The returned variable is `newN`.

In script file, for example called `test.m`:

```
%Entry Point
clear all

N = 100;
x = randn(1,N);

% this map will store everything u want to return from myFunction.
returnMap = containers.Map;

figHandle = figure(1);
clf(figHandle);
set(figHandle, 'KeyPressFcn', ...
    @(fig_obj , eventDat) myFunction(fig_obj, eventDat, x, N, returnMap));


% wait till gui finishes in this example.
waitfor(figHandle);

newN = returnMap('newN');

% display newN
newN
```

In a file called `myFunction.m`:

```
function myFunction(handle, eventDat, x, N, returnMap)

    mean = sum(x)/N;
    disp(mean);
    key = eventDat.Key;
    disp(key);

    newN = 435;

    returnMap('newN') = newN;
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin - but as I am saying, I would like it to NOT be through a function. That is, I cannot use 'function test1()' as you have. The entry point is a script as you see. I can call a function later, but the entry point is a script. Thanks!

Comment: @Learnaholic Not sure if I understand, but u can put `myFunction` in a file called `myFunction.m`. Does it have to be in the same script as the entry point?

Comment: Marcin - ok, what I mean is: I can only have two files. The first file will be the entry point, and it is just a script. Literally, the first line is clear all. The second file will be myFunction, and this file WILL be a function. So literally the first line is function myFunction as you have. Make sense? The entry point is NOT a function... here your entry point is a function you have named test1. I dont want that. The entry point is just a script...

Comment: You put a 'function test1()' before my first line, to make the whole thing a function. But I cannot do that. The first like IS 'clear all'. Entry point is a script, not a function.

Comment: @Learnaholic I amended the answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Ok, so the new problem is that I need to pass N back from the myFunction, and reuse the value in the script again, etc. I have used a global variable to fix that for now. Is there a better way? Otherwise, this is ok thanks! :-)

Comment: @Learnaholic I added one example. Difficult to say more, as there are many possibilities and it depends on what you want to do.