# Animate a MATLAB figure by pressing left and right arrow keys

Tags: matlab, callback, pass-by-reference, matlab-figure

I am trying to change the radius of a sphere by using left and right arrow keys, plotted in a MATLAB figure. For example by pressing right arrow, the value of radius increases by one and then plot the new sphere with the updated radius. Similarly, pressing left arrow key decreases the radius by one and then plots a smaller sphere. However, I want this change to be limited between 1 and `rmax`.

I got some ideas of how I can approach after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19579258/1227860) but still it is not what I am looking for. Therefore, I used two global variables to achieve this task in order to somehow pass the information by reference to `KeyPressFcn` so when a key is pressed `KeyPressFcn` know what those limits are. In the example below, the code does increase and decrease the radius by one but it is it does not restrict the change of radius within the specified range after left and right arrows are hit.

Is there a better way of approaching this? How can I pass the value of radius and its limits to `KeyPressFcn`? I want `KeyPressFcn` to know how much it can change the radius when left and right arrows are pressed.

```
function animateme()

fig_h = figure;
set(fig_h,'KeyPressFcn', @key_pressed_fcn);

global r rmax

p0 = [0 0 0];
[x,y,z] = sphere; 

rmax = 10;
r = 1;

while 1==1

    h = surf(x*r+p0(1), y*r+p0(2), z*r+p0(3)); 
    set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, 'FaceColor', rand([1 3]))
    axis equal;

    pause

end



function key_pressed_fcn(fig_obj, eventDat)

global r rmax

if strcmpi(eventDat.Key, 'rightarrow')
    r = r + 1;
    if r < 1
        r = 1;
    end
elseif strcmpi(eventDat.Key, 'leftarrow')
    r = r - 1;
    if r > rmax
        r = rmax;
    end
end
disp(r)
```

Comment: Your right and left arrow logic is backwards.

Comment: Thank you for the great catch. It does the job perfectly. Still one question, how would you approach to pass `r` and `rmax` to `KeyPressFcn` by reference?

Comment: See: [How to Specify Callback Property Values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#brqow8p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use global variables as there is (almost) always a better way of accomplishing the same thing.

Here is an example by using nested functions which automatically have access to the variables within the parent function's workspace.

```
function animateme()
    fig = figure();
    hax = axes('Parent', fig);
    set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', @keypress)

    p0 = [0,0,0];
    [x,y,z] = sphere();

    % Specify limits here which are accessible to nested functions
    rmax = 10;
    r = 1;

    h = surf(x,y,z, 'Parent', hax);

    % Subfunction for re-plotting the data
    % This prevents you from needing a while loop
    function redraw()
        set(h, 'XData', x * r + p0(1), ...
               'YData', y * r + p0(2), ...)
               'ZData', z * r + p0(3));

        set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, ...
               'FaceColor', rand([1 3]))

        axis(hax, 'equal')
        drawnow
    end

    % Go ahead and do the first redraw
    redraw();

    % Callback to process keypress events
    function keypress(~, evnt)
        switch lower(evnt.Key)
            case 'rightarrow'
                r = min(r + 1, rmax);
            case 'leftarrow'
                r = max(1, r - 1);
            otherwise
                return
        end

        % Always do a redraw
        redraw();
    end
end
```

Another option is to store the current value of `r` within the graphics objects themselves using the `UserData` field. So you could put it in the `surf` plot itself. This is actually my preferred method because then your callback function can live anywhere and still have access to the data it needs.

```
function animateme()

    fig = figure();

    % Data to store for plotting
    data.p = [0,0,0];
    data.r = 1;
    data.rmax = 10;

    % Create a blank surface for starters
    h = surf(nan(2), nan(2), nan(2));
    set(h, 'UserData', data);

    % Update the display of the surface
    redraw(h);

    % Set the callback and pass the surf handle
    set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', @(fig, evnt)keypress(h, evnt))
end

function redraw(h)

    % Get the stored data from the graphics object
    userdata = get(h, 'Userdata');

    [x,y,z] = sphere();

    set(h, 'XData', x * userdata.r + userdata.p(1), ...
           'YData', y * userdata.r + userdata.p(2), ...
           'ZData', z * userdata.r + userdata.p(3));

    set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5, ...
           'FaceColor', rand([1 3]))

    axis equal
    drawnow;
end

function keypress(h, evnt)

    % Get the stored data
    userdata = get(h, 'Userdata');

    switch lower(evnt.Key)
        case 'rightarrow'
            userdata.r = min(userdata.r + 1, userdata.rmax);
        case 'leftarrow'
            userdata.r = max(1, userdata.r - 1);
        otherwise
            return;
    end

    % Update the stored value
    set(h, 'UserData', userdata);

    redraw(h);
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Can this be adapted to a MATLAB `trisurf` plot? Because my ultimate goal is to use the approach in this answer to plot triangulated 3D surfaces shaded by a scalar function.

Comment: @Ahmad the logic for passing data between functions remains the same regardless of what time of plot, you'd just need to update the plot commands to the correct type for your usecase.

Comment: @Ahmad I have updated my answer to include a second option which is a bit more flexible but still applies to all types of graphics.

Comment: Excellent job! This is what I was looking for to save the data within the graphics object.